# Excel Formula: Lookup from multiple named ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect, excel-match

I have 3 Tables stored as named ranges.
The user picks which range to search through using a drop down box. The named ranges are `Table1`, `Table2` and `Table 3`.

Table1

```
    0.7     0.8     0.9
50  1.08    1.06    1.04
70  1.08    1.06    1.05
95  1.08    1.07    1.05
120 1.09    1.07    1.05
```

Table2

```
    0.7     0.8     0.9
16  1.06    1.04    1.03
25  1.06    1.05    1.03
35  1.06    1.05    1.03
```

Table 3

```
    0.7     0.8     0.9
50  1.21    1.16    1.11
70  1.22    1.16    1.12
95  1.22    1.16    1.12
120 1.22    1.16    1.12
```

Then they pick a value from the header row, and a value from the first column.
i.e. the user picks, `Table3`, `0.8` and `95`. My formula should return `1.16`.

I am halfway there using `indirect` (`table1`), however I need to extract the header row, and first column so I can use something like

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(pickedtable),MATCH(picked colref,INDIRECT(pickedtable:1)), MATCH(picked rowref,INDIRECT(1:pickedtable)))
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about "Excel tables", i.e. you created it using Insert->Table? Can you paste a link to a screenshot for better clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDIRECT(pickedtable)` should work OK to get the table but to get first column or row from the table you can use `INDEX` with that, so following your original approach this formula should work

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(pickedtable),MATCH(pickedcolref,INDEX(INDIRECT(pickedtable),0,1),0),MATCH(pickedrowref,INDEX(INDIRECT(pickedtable),1,0),0))
```

or you can use `HLOOKUP` or `VLOOKUP` to shorten as per chris neilsen's approach, e.g. with `VLOOKUP`

```
=VLOOKUP(pickedcolref,INDIRECT(pickedtable),MATCH(pickedrowref,INDEX(INDIRECT(pickedtable),1,0),0))
```

Comment: I was so close to this, I had tried using index with an offset but I was getting the syntax wrong. This is exactly what I was looking for.Thanks Heaps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=HLOOKUP(pickedcolref,
  IF(pickedtable=1,Table1,IF(pickedtable=2,Table2,IF(pickedtable=3,Table3,""))),
  MATCH(pickedrowref,
    OFFSET(
      IF(pickedtable=1,Table1,IF(pickedtable=2,Table2,IF(pickedtable=3,Table3,""))),
    0,0,,1)
  ,0)
 ,FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know how to use offset properly until I saw this post.